# How can I check closest parent classname in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, parent, closest, classname

I want to check classname which the closest parent of the clicked element in angular 6?

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent-element selected" (click)="checkClass($event)">
    <ul>
         <li><a>Link-1</a></li>
         <li><a>Link-2</a></li>
         <li><a>Link-3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**ANGULAR**

```
checkClass(element) {
 return element.target.classList.contains('selected');
}
```

if I check the classname by using "checkClass" function, it doesn't always give the right result, because there is a possibility of clicked element other than a parent. So I want to first find the closest parent of the clicked element and than check the classname. How can I do that?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442576/parents-in-angular) might help

Comment: right off the bat. I'd suggest assigning values to arbitrarily create priority of children or giving them some type of weight such as an id and then target that instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$event.target.parentNode;` will give you parent element.

you can get parent element by this:

```
 $event.target.parentElement
```

and all the class list by this:

```
 $event.target.parentElement.classList;
```

Comment: it doesn't give the closest parent, it just take first parent